# How to configure BPMN Activity job/task priority

Tags: java, activiti, bpmn

We are using the activity BPMN engine (version 5.20.0) to model workflow. Is any way to force/configure the framework to start some serviceTasks (jobs?) before others? The expected result is when many jobs are waiting to run activity executes first those with the highest priority.

Answer (score 0):

The BPMN model should define the order of processing, if you are talking about parallel flow paths, you could use events to effectively release tasks to control order of processing. However, if you need to go to this level of effort, then why are the services modeled in parallel?